# Launch4j only shows program name/icon in Taskmanager when Header is 'Console'

Tags: java, wrapper, taskmanager, launch4j

When I set the Header type to 'GUI', the Windows Taskmanager shows 'Java(TM) Platform SE binary'.
When I change to Header type 'Console', program name and icon are shown correctly.

Is there a way to show program name and icon in Windows Tasknamager also when Header type is set to 'GUI' ?

Comment: That used to be a good feature of the past, due to vista additional UAC permissions and invocation of administrative privileges screen, this was [dropped](https://sourceforge.net/p/launch4j/bugs/27/).

Comment: @RajeevSreedharan So no way? Anything planned? Because the old JSmooth is doing that but I would prefer Launch4j for many reasons ..

Comment: Indeed it would be very nice, if one could set the proper app name...